# VSTS Update build via REST API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-sdk

My goal is to update the build's pool information to move the queued build/build into another pool via the REST API. I have tried a lot of things and cannot find any documentation - not even on which parameters can actually be set

Code I have tried to accomplish this task with:

```
try
{
    build.Queue.Id = newQueue.Id;
    build.Queue.Name = newQueue.Name;
    build.Queue.Pool = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.TaskAgentPoolReference();
    build.Queue.Pool.Name = newQueue.Pool.Name;
    build.Queue.Pool.Id = newQueue.Pool.Id;
    build.Queue.Pool.IsHosted = newQueue.Pool.IsHosted;
    var c = connection.GetBuildClient();
    var tf = await  c.UpdateBuildAsync(build);

    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return false;
}
```

(the above code is very hacky as I am attempting to make it work)

---

### Things I have tried:

1) I have tried copying the exact json and sending it via a raw patch request, then I get a response saying that it is modified. But NOTHING is modified except the last modified user changing to me

2) I have tried editing the AgentsPoolQueue in the request body via the API, but it is not the pool I want to change - but the Build's pool information to link to another build instead.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT I have updated the question including that I even tried a raw patch request, and got a valid response but nothing is changing on the actual Azure I am trying to modify.

Comment: Updating the queued build's agent pool through the rest api is not supported in Azure Devops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> update the build's pool information to move the queued build/build
>   into another pool via the REST API

After testing, updating the queued build's agent pool through the rest API is currently not supported in Azure Devops . Once build is run, its agent pool information cannot be modified.

Although the `AgentPoolQueue` is recorded in the request body in the [Update-build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update%20build?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#request-body) rest api document. However, when you actually use it, you will find that the return status is `200 ok`, but the pool information in the build has not actually been updated. This is not stated in the documentation and it does cause confusion.

The agent pool is determined when you run pipeline. Once the build is running, even in the queue state, it cannot be changed. You could submit your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. More votes and comments can increase the priority of feedback.

At present, you can only cancel the queued builds, run new builds, and re-specify the agent pool in the new builds.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/850582/support-to-update-a-quueed-builds-agent-pool-throu.html
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the Build using the existing Build id

```
public async Task<Build> UpdateBuildAsync(Build build, string id)
        {
            var updateBuild = await Repository.GetBuildAsync(id);
            if (updateBuild != null)
            {
                updateBuild.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                updateBuild.Status = build.Status;
                updateBuild.Description = build.Description;
                if (build.Status == (int)BuildStatus.BuildQueued)
                {
                    updateBuild.VSTSBuildId = build.VSTSBuildId;
                }
                if (build.Status == (int)BuildStatus.DeploymentQueued)
                {
                    updateBuild.TemplateParameterUri = build.TemplateParameterUri;
                    updateBuild.TemplateUri = build.TemplateUri;
                }
                updateBuild.PkgURL = build.PkgURL;
                await Repository.UpdateBuildAsync(updateBuild);
                return await Repository.GetBuildAsync(id);
            }
            return updateBuild;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, it is the pool information of the build I am trying to update - not the build itself

Comment: still you need to pass the id i think